# UML aggregation/association to XML Schema

Tags: xsd, mapping, associations, uml, aggregation

long story short:
I want to genererate XSD from UML for this I need a way to represent UML aggregation/association in XSD. I found a mapping an they recommend (for aggregation/association) : "reference element with IDREF attribute and referencing the associated class and keyref for type saftey (key/keyref reference)". But I dont know how to do this exactly because I'm really new in XSD ( < 1 week).

So this is what I thought it should look like but im not sure^^ Does anybody has some advices or can correct if my code has errors?

uml: http://i39.tinypic.com/15x8ufp.png

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns="namespace" targetNamespace="namespaceURI">
    <xsd:import namespace="namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:element name="classA">         
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
         <xsd:element name="attributeElement" />
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:attribute name="aId" type="xsd:ID" use="required" />
      </xsd:complexType>    
      <xsd:key name="classAKey">
        <xsd:selector xpath="ns:root/ns:classA" />
        <xsd:field xpath="@aId" />
      </xsd:key>                        
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="classB">         
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
         <xsd:element name="refClassA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:all>
        <xsd:attribute name="bId" type="xsd:ID" use="required" />
      </xsd:complexType>    
      <xsd:key name="classBKey">
        <xsd:selector xpath="ns:root/ns:classB" />
        <xsd:field xpath="@bId" />
      </xsd:key>
      <xsd:keyref name="classARef" refer="ns:classAKey">
          <xsd:selector xpath="ns:classB" />
          <xsd:field xpath="./refClassA" />
      </xsd:keyref>                     
    </xsd:element>

            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>    
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [UML For W3C XML Schema Design](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1011) will help answer your questions.  It is old, but the basics of what it shows still apply today and is pretty clearly presented.

Comment: Your link is now broken. Perhaps it would be best to find where this link has moved to, and then include relevant text from the link which answers the OP question. This will help people looking for the same answer now and in the future.